# When to initially load state from database with Vuex

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, vuex

I have a pretty basic vue/vuex project, and I load a list of categories from my database via a Http get request. Before incorporating Vuex into my project, I was just making the HTTP get right when I create my main component that uses the data. Now, in Vuex I have my getters and mutations and actions, but, what I don't clearly get is the proper way (or place) with Vuex to do that get and fill the state object categories. I could still run the Get in my component create and then fill the Vuex state through the actions, but that seems kind of backwards. Hoping someone can point me to the proper "best practice" way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of running the request from your component and filling the state with the results, you can dispatch an action which makes the request and commits the mutation with the results. If you want it to happen immediately, dispatch the actions from the create method of the root vue node.

Comment: So, basically just make an action that's job is to fill it? I think I sort of have a misconception that actions are just for setting values, but really they could be used for anything related to the state right?

Comment: Actions allow you to do async operations, and use the result to commit to mutate the store. Mutations must be syncronous. I would create an action for each api call, though.

Comment: Take a look at this sample app https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart

Comment: Super helpful, thanks Ben. I see they use that shop.js file to pretend to be the api part. I think this is what I needed.